# Change Text link color swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, swiftui

I have the folowing `Text()` that takes markdown to show a link

```
Text(.init("[Link Example](https://www.google.es/)"))
```

[image: Example of my text]

Is there a way of changing the default color set to the link?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is possible to use accent color, like

```
Text(.init("[Link Example](https://www.google.es/)"))
    .accentColor(.red)
```

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 19):

You can achieve that with `.tint(_:)` as `accentColor(_:)` will soon be deprecated according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/accentcolor(_:)).

```
Text("[Link Example](https://www.google.es/)")
  .tint(Color.red)
```

Comment: doesn't work too

Comment: The best way would be to use an `AttributedString` in `Text`, and define the `foregroundColor` on the range of the text where the link is added. Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71446034/how-to-change-hyper-link-text-color-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 0):

Link color is the default accent color of the app which is blue.

You can change this by setting a custom accent color:

1. Add a color set in your Assets.xcassets
2. In target -> Build settings, search for "Global Accent Color Name"
3. Double click on it and set the color name aded in step 1

Thats it..!